# How to properly embed script tags from 3rd party vendor into into rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using a really handy service called typecast.  One of the perks is that there are licensing agreements with different font providers, myfonts, fonts.com, etc.

To access the fonts you've designed with, typecast gives you an embed link like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://typecast.com/project_css/DBmVWZKx7n/164947d5a8ce64.js"></script>
```

I'm developing this in a rails app (Rails 4) and to quickly see the results, I am putting the above script at the bottom of my application layout file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<%= yield :head %>

<body class="page">
    <div class="ca-root"> <!-- root element required for sticky footer -->

        <%= yield :header %>
        <%= yield :hero %>
        <%= yield :main_content %>


        <div class="ca-root-footer"></div>  <!-- Need this elementfor the sticky footer -->
    </div>     <!-- End root for sticky footer -->

<%= yield :footer %>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript"         

src="http://typecast.com/project_css/DBmVWZKx7n/164947d5a8ce64.js"></script>
```

This gives me a strange 502 bad gateway error.  Is it something I'm doing wrong with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the next line inside the `body` tag?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://typecast.com/project_css/DBmVWZKx7n/164947d5a8ce64.js' %>
```

Just after `<%= yield :footer %>`.